# Using PrintDocument to print an image to the printer without margins

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, .net-4.8

I'm trying to use a PrintDocument object to print an image to the printer but the image keeps coming out cut off a little on the right side.

```
private PrintDocument _printDocument;
public void PrintCurrentPage()
{
    _printPage = 1;

    if (_printDocument != null)
    {
        try
        {
            _printDocument.Print();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}

private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int savePage = iv.Image.Page;
    try
    {
        iv.Image.Page = _printPage;
        _printPage++;

        using (Image img = RasterImageConverter.ConvertToImage(iv.Image, ConvertToImageOptions.None))
        {
            if (LeadToolsHelper.CanRunPrintPreview)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        e.HasMorePages = _printPage <= iv.Image.PageCount;
        if (_printPage > iv.Image.PageCount)
            _printPage = 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        iv.Image.Page = savePage;
    }
}
```

I suspect (but not 100% sure) that it has something to do with the margins.  I tried adding the following with no luck.

```
_printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
_printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;
_printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
_printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;

_printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
_printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;
_printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
_printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
```

Any ideas how I can make the print coming out to fit the page/paper size and not print of the paper?

Comment: How much is *a little*? Cut only on the right, or also *a little* at the bottom? -- After you set the margins, when you receive the `PrintPageEventArgs` in `PrintPage()`, what measures can you read there? Why are you not specifying the full size of the rendering in `DrawImage()`, just the origin point?

Comment: A little = about the size of what I would think two margins (left/right) would look like.  The document I'm testing with has a bunch of blank space but from the looks of it I think the bottom is getting cut off too. I set those margins BEFORE calling `_printDocument.Print();`.  Without using a width or height it uses the defaults which seem to size the image to the bounds of the Margins or at least the page width/height.

Comment: As mentioned, have you checked, in `PrinDocument()`, what are the `e.PageSettings.PrintableArea` and `e.PageSettings.Margins` properties set to at that time? It might not be what you have set before (i.e., the Printer's driver has not accepted your settings). You should also set the resolution of the Bitmap (`[Bitmap].SetResolution()`) to the Printer's (`e.PageSettings.PrinterResolution`) -- You should always specify a Rectangle in `DrawImage()` (unless you don't care what's going to be or you already know, because the image is sized - and its resolution set -  in a specific way)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across some more info on a Microsoft site and ended up coming out with the following to solve my issue.  It works great and the image is now centered perfectly within the bounds of the page.

```
public class MyFancyPrintClass: UserControl
{
    private PrintDocument _printDocument;
    private PrintAction printAction = PrintAction.PrintToPrinter;
    private int _printPage;
    
    
    // Constructor
    public MyFancyPrintClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Check if there is printer installed
        try
        {
            if (PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters != null && PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count > 0)
            {
                _printDocument = new PrintDocument();
                _printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintDocument_PrintPage);
                _printDocument.BeginPrint += new PrintEventHandler(PrintDocument_BeginPrint);
            }
            else
                _printDocument = null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _printDocument = null;
        }
    }
    
    
    // Methods
    public void PrintCurrentPage()
    {
        _printPage = 1;

        if (_printDocument != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_printDocument.PrinterSettings.CanDuplex)
                    _printDocument.PrinterSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Vertical;

                _printDocument.Print();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    // Printer events
    private void PrintDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save our print action so we know if we are printing 
        // a preview or a real document.
        printAction = e.PrintAction;

        // Set some preferences, our method should print a box with any 
        // combination of these properties being true/false.
        _printDocument.OriginAtMargins = false;   //true = soft margins, false = hard margins
        _printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
    }

    private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // The "iv" object is an object I have that contains my Image.  Change it to your control's name.
        
        int savePage = iv.Image.Page;

        try
        {
            iv.Image.Page = _printPage;
            _printPage++;

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            RectangleF marginBounds = e.MarginBounds;
            RectangleF printableArea = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;

            if (printAction == PrintAction.PrintToPreview)
                g.TranslateTransform(printableArea.X, printableArea.Y);

            int availableWidth = (int)Math.Floor(_printDocument.OriginAtMargins
                ? marginBounds.Width
                : (e.PageSettings.Landscape
                ? printableArea.Height
                : printableArea.Width));

            int availableHeight = (int)Math.Floor(_printDocument.OriginAtMargins
                ? marginBounds.Height
                : (e.PageSettings.Landscape
                ? printableArea.Width
                : printableArea.Height));

            using (Image img = RasterImageConverter.ConvertToImage(iv.Image, ConvertToImageOptions.None))
            {
                //g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, availableWidth - 1, availableHeight - 1);
                g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, availableWidth - 1, availableHeight - 1);
            }

            e.HasMorePages = _printPage <= iv.Image.PageCount;
            if (_printPage > iv.Image.PageCount)
                _printPage = 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Go to the next page if there is one
            iv.Image.Page = savePage;
        }
    }
}
```